# How can I transfer photos from an old Canon Rebel EOS 350D to my computer?

Tags: compatibility, file-transfer, canon-350d

I inherited an old Canon Rebel EOS 350D. I cannot get the camera to hook up to my HP computer and upload the pictures. It uses an old card that doesn't fit, but I have it hooked up with a cord that fits both the camera and my PC.

And yes, I did install the Canon photo program onto my computer — it tells me it's not finding the camera. I've tried all 4 ports on my PC and it rings when I plug it in. I'd like to see what the pictures look like before I sell the camera.

Comment: What OS are you using on your HP computer? Which Canon photo program did you install?

Comment: Wow, inherited ?

Answer (score 6):

This camera uses Compact Flash (CF) cards. You can buy a decent multiple-format USB card reader which has CF support for under $20. You can even buy just-CF readers for less than that. This should Just Work, without any hassle. And, as a bonus, if you're planning to sell the camera, you can thrown in the reader so that your buyer doesn't have any hassle either.

Comment: this seems a much better idea than getting the camera recognized by current OS

Comment: @JindraLacko the camera shouldn't need drivers and will be recognized by any relatively modern OS if it's set to behave as a Mass Storage device. In such mode the camera effectively acts as a card reader.

Comment: I still sometimes use a 350D (a DSLR, even an ancient one, is handy in an optics lab).  On Win7 I've found a cheap card reader (under $10) to be the best solution.  My Linux box at home talks to the camera with no explicit need to install software, but the card reader is *more* convenient (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Try toggling the `Communication` setting. Some users report that  `Print/PTP` works for them (confusingly, this is the setting that should be used in order to connect the camera directly to certain Canon printers). Others report that `PC connection` is the correct setting.

Press the <kbd>Menu</kbd> button to bring up the menus. Press the <kbd>Jump</kbd> button, or use <kbd>◀︎</kbd>/<kbd>▶</kbd> buttons, until the Set-up 2 menu (yellow, looks like wrench+hammer "2") is highlighted. Under `Communication`, try changing the option (it will be either `Print/PTP` or `PC connection`).

[image: Connection menu instruction manual page 120 of Canon EOS 250D User Manual]
<sup>*Taken from page 120 of the [Canon EOS 250D User Manual](http://files.canon-europe.com/files/soft29409/Manual/EOS_350D_hardware_Eng_toc.pdf)*</sup>

If that doesn't work, you will need to use a CompactFlash card reader to get the photos off of the CF card and onto your computer. They can be had for as little at $10 USD at various retailers online.

---

**Sources**

Note that because of the age of the camera (it was introduced in 2005), many of the support references are to older versions of Windows.

- User "Stigv"'s answer to [Canon EOS 350D camera don´t connect to Windows 7 Professional](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/canon-eos-350d-camera-dont-connect-to-windows-7/23137c7e-ec79-489c-989b-7cff1d1397e0) at answers.microsoft.com.
- [Unable to connect 350d with PC](http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=147428) discussion at photography-on-the.net forums.
- [Canon EOS 350D and Windows 7 x64 – Where are the Drivers, Canon?](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2009/08/canon-eos-350d-and-windows-7-x64-where-are-the-drivers-canon/) at helgeklein.com.

Comment: Changing the communication setting worked for me.. lifesaver!!!